# Breeze not updating after save. View with 1 to 0..1 relationship to table

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I have a view and a table that has a 1 to 0..1 relationship.  Everything works fine if there is a record in the table but I'm having trouble when I create a record.

Here is the code:

```
function orderVerified(order) {
    if (order.approvals) {
        order.approvals.isApproved = true;
    } else {
        datacontext.order.createApproval(order.id, order.type);
    }
    save(order);
}

function createApproval(id, type) {
   return this.manager.createEntity("SalesOrdersApproval",
            {id: id, type: type, isApproved: true});
}
```

This works and if if a record doesn't exist my database is updated as I would expect.  The problem is when the else condition is met and I need to create the record my UI isn't updated.

I tried changing my orderVerified function to this but the new line throws an error:

```
function orderVerified(order) {
    if (order.approvals) {
        order.approvals.isApproved = true;
    } else {
        var a = datacontext.eaorder.createApproval(order.id, order.type);
        order.approvals = a; //this line throws the error below
    }
    save(order);
}
```

Error:
Save failed: Unable to update the EntitySet 'vwEaSalesOrdersPickupsCombined' because it has a DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the  element to support the current operation.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I added this on the server and now the line

```
order.approvals = a;
```

no longer throws the error and my UI updates as expected.

```
protected override bool BeforeSaveEntity(EntityInfo entityInfo)
    {
        var entity = entityInfo.Entity;
        if (entity is EaSalesOrdersPickupsCombined)  //the name of the view
        {
            return false;   //don't update
        }
        return true;
    }
```